# Why wouldn't this d3 chart render?

Tags: javascript, html, charts, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am trying to get a super basic nvd3 chart rendering.  The code looks something like this ([fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/NxxRH/)):

```
<div id="chart" class="chart with-transitions">
    <svg></svg>
</div>
```

and

```
nv.addGraph({
  generate: function() {

    var chart = nv.models.line()
                .margin({top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20})
    d3.select('#chart')
      .datum(sinAndCos())
      .call(chart);

    return chart;
  }});


    function sinAndCos() {
      var sin = [],
          cos = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        sin.push({x: i, y: Math.sin(i/10)});
        cos.push({x: i, y: .5 * Math.cos(i/10)});
      }

      return [
        {
          values: sin,
          key: "Sine Wave",
          color: "#ff7f0e"
        },
        {
          values: cos,
          key: "Cosine Wave",
          color: "#2ca02c"
        }
      ];
    }
```

But when I run this nothing happens.  No errors generated, no chart displayed.  I copied/modified this code from the most basic example they offer, but I can't seem to figure out what I broke.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NxxRH/1/)

```
<div id="chart" class="chart with-transitions">
    <svg height="500"></svg>
</div>
```

...

```
d3.select('#chart svg')
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NxxRH/2/)**

You forgot to select the `svg` element that you  want to render your chart in. Also, call `lineChart()` instead of `line()` if you want to display the axis and other information:

```
var chart = nv.models.lineChart() <-- lineChart()
                .margin({top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20});
    d3.select('#chart svg') <-- include svg
      .datum(sinAndCos())
      .call(chart);
```